# Background Images in HTML E-mails

Tags: html, image, background, email

Is it possible to have image backgrounds inside HTML e-mails that are displayed across webmail as well as locally installed mail clients?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many clients strip out image backgrounds in HTML e-mails for security reasons. So there is to my knowledge no way to make absolutely certain that the image is displayed.

For example, [this way](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3170/adding-background-images-to-your-email-in-two-simple-steps/) does not work for people viewing the mail in Outlook.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no. If you are wanting to use CSS to set a `background-image` then you will find that this will not work in a number of web and desktop clients (especially Outlook), and it is considered best practice to avoid using them.

The preferred solution is to create a design which can be built using `<img />` tags instead. This will have much more consistant results across all web and desktop clients.